# How to correctly implement an insertion sort algorithm in a 2D array?

Tags: c, arrays, insertion-sort

I need to sort the columns of my 2D array based on the first row of the array. This is my 2d array before sorting:

```
cargo

AFADA
DAFGF
DXAFA
DDFFX
GFXF
```

and this is the image of my 2D array:

```
acrgo

FAADA
ADFGF
XDAFA
DDFFX
FGXF
```

The correct output looks like this

```
acgor

FADAA
ADGFF
XDFAA
DDFXF
FGF X
```

. This is the code of my function to sort the array using insertion sort algorithm

```
void sort(char** newTable, int row, int col) {
    for (int top = 1; top < col; col++) {
        char item = newTable[0][top];
        int i = top;
        while (i > 0 && item < newTable[0][i - 1]) {
            for (int j = 0; j < row + 1; j++) {
                char temp = newTable[j][i];
                newTable[j][i] = newTable[j][i - 1];
                newTable[j][i - 1] = temp;
            }
            i--;
         }
         newTable[0][i] = item;
     }
 }
```

I called the function like this

```
    sort(newTable, row, strlen(key));
```

here, key is the string 'cargo'

The definition of newTable:

```
char** newTable = (char**)calloc(row + 1, sizeof(char*));
    for (int i = 0; i < row + 1; i++) {
        newTable[i] = (char*)calloc(strlen(key), sizeof(char));
    }
```

Comment: I am trying to sort the first row alphabetically and shift the columns below it accordingly

Comment: If  the spacing in the last line is to be ignored, it is better to say that in the post, perhaps just to the right of the text of that last line `//ignore space` or just don't show the space in your data: `FGFX`.

Comment: Yeah, i fixed that

Comment: Can you also include a short snippet showing how you call this function, i.e. show the input, and how you read the results.  By the way, to get results you will need to pass the address of the 2D array to allow changes made in the function to be retrieved, requiring `char** newTable` to become `char ***newTable` in the prototype.  Then called as (for example) `sort(&some2DArray, 6,5);`

Comment: i added the snippet on how i called the function. I think that there is some error in my implementation of the sorting algorithm cos it is sorting it partially correct

Comment: I do not see what the objective is for sorting each row.  They are not alphabetical.  What is your criteria.?  (i.e. how does `AFADA` become `FADAA` in the first row?)

Comment: To be a [mcve], we need the definition of `newtable` and of `row`. And I hope that `newtable` is not a 2D array but is an array of pointers...

Comment: it should sort the 1st row which is 'cargo' alphabetically to 'acgor'. and the rows below are unchanged

Comment: @SergeBallesta row is of `int` type and I'm adding `newTable` definition to the question

Comment: The code you have shown is difficult to imagine working, since it would require 1) as mentioned before that the prototype requires ability to accept the _address of_ the data array to be changed: likely using the `&` operator on for example `&array` if `array` is created as `char **array`, and is allocated memory.  2) occrrances of `newTable`  in your function would then require to be _dereferenced_, for example: `*(newTable[j][i]) = *(newTable[j][i - 1]);` to allow changes made in code to be retrieved in the calling function.

Comment: _and the rows below are unchanged_  It does not appear that the other rows are unchanged...  original: `AFADA`, sorted: `FAADA`, correct sort: `FADAA`.  is the data shown inaccurately in the post? above?

Comment: No, it's correct. Only the first row is sorted.

Comment: Why are you saying then that in the _correct_ block of data, that the second line `FADAA` is unchanged from the original, `AFADA`.  They are not the same.

Answer (score 1):

`newTable` is indeed an array of pointers and not a 2D array, so using `char **newTable` makes sense.

The major error is close to a typo: in the first `for` loop of `sort`, you increment `col` when you want to increment `top`. And the last line `newTable[0][i] = item;` is useless.

This should work (even if the loop `for (int j = 0; j < row + 1; j++)` suggests that row is not the number of rows in `newTable` but only the number of *additional rows):

```
void sort(char** newTable, int row, int col) {
    for (int top = 1; top < col; top++) {
        char item = newTable[0][top];
        int i = top;
        while (i > 0 && item < newTable[0][i - 1]) {
            for (int j = 0; j < row + 1; j++) {
                char temp = newTable[j][i];
                newTable[j][i] = newTable[j][i - 1];
                newTable[j][i - 1] = temp;
            }
            i--;
         }
     }
 }
```

Comment: Will this actually allow caller to see the changes made in the array?  Doesn't caller have to pass the _address of_, therefore requring prototype to use `char ***array` ?

Comment: @ryyker: You have to pass a pointer if you want to build a brand new array in the function. Here you just change elements inside the really same array, so you do not need an additional indirection level.